# Как сделать так чтобы выпадающее меню не заезжало за правый край браузера

Tags: bootstrap

Использую Bootstrap 4 чтобы сделать навигационное меню. Необходимо часть элементов nav-item поместить у правого края navbar, при этом самый правый из них имеет выпадающее меню.

Проблема в том, что ширина выпадающего меню значительно больше чем ширина nav-item, и почему-то не зависит от ширины текста в списке меню. Поэтому список выезжает за край браузера, когда открывается.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light navbar-light fixed-top">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">App Name</a>
    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <!-- Authentication Links -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">User Name <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Чтобы воспроизвести проблему в приведенном выше сниппете, необходимо выполнить его, а затем нажать на кнопку "На всю страницу". На маленьких экранах работает иначе, и эта конкретная проблема воспроизводится только на десктопе.

Я пробовал вынести `<div class="dropdown-menu">` за границы родительского `<li>`, в надежде что тогда список будет отталкиваться от правого края браузера. Но в таком случае список просто не открывается.

Воспроизводится в Chrome и Safari.

Chrome: Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build)

Safari: Version 10.1.2 (12603.3.8)

Comment: а Вам надо, чтобы на десктопе было также, как сейчас на мобильном?

Comment: Не, как сейчас на мобильном тоже как-то не хорошо, но это уже наверное отдельный вопрос. На десктопе нужно именно так как сейчас, но чтобы между правым краем меню и правым краем браузера был небольшой промежуток. Сейчас левый край меню выравнивается по левому краю родительского элемента. Возможно, надо родительский элемент просто сделать пошире.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Элемент `.dropdown-menu` в Bootstrap 4 выравнивается по левому краю контейнера с помощью абсолютного позиционирования: `left: 0`. Чтобы переопределить это выравнивание, нужно добавить к раскрывающемуся списку еще один класс, который заставляет его выравниваться по правому краю, но только для средних экранов (планшет) и более широких:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-menu-right {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
  }
}
```

Более того, как выяснилось после внимательного прочтения [документации](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/), такой класс уже существует в самом фреймворке. Информация находилась в разделе Menu Alignment:

> By default, a dropdown menu is automatically positioned 100% from the
>   top and along the left side of its parent. Add .dropdown-menu-right to
>   a .dropdown-menu to right align the dropdown menu.

Таким образом, решение заключается в добавлении класса `.dropdown-menu-right` на элемент с классом `.dropdown-menu`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light navbar-light fixed-top">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">App Name</a>
    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <!-- Authentication Links -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">User Name <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Переназначить стиль надо

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style> 
.dropdown-menu{
  margin-left:-40px;
  background:blue;
}
</style>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light navbar-light fixed-top">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">App Name</a>
    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <!-- Authentication Links -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">User Name <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**а дальше использовать медиа запросы что бы исправить на других разрешениях экрана**

Comment: К сожалению, такой способ не сработает, потому что текст в меню (User Name) не статический. Он может быть любой - admin, Katerina, Captian RedBeard, и.т.д. Я нашел другое решение, и опубликовал ответ под вашим. Тем не менее, ваш ответ мне помог, и в моем вопросе не было дополнительных условий насчет динамического текста, поэтому я оставил его как принятый.